# Why doesn't the screen command source my .profile?

Tags: terminal, command-line, screen, bash

When I start a new screen, the aliases that I have set in my `~/.profile` do not seem to be sourced.

Does anyone know where I can change this or which file is actually read when starting a new screen?

Comment: Doesn't `screen -l` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an alias to work in ~/.profile the session needs to be a login shell. Bash, which is probably what you're using, is typically read from ~/.bash_profile.

There's a good explanation of the differences mentioned here:

https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile

Comment: Bash does use .profile iff .bash_profile does not exist. I think you mean .bashrc for a non login shell

Answer (score 4):

Apple uses ~/.bash_profile as mentioned above. If you want bash inside screen to behave exactly as the Apple Terminal, create a ~/.bashrc file with the command

```
source /etc/profile
```

which will include all Apple settings.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `~/.screenrc`:

```
shell -$SHELL
```

As per [here](https://superuser.com/questions/314564/mac-gnu-screen-doesnt-load-default-bash-profile)

This ensures screen interprets your bash invocation as a login shell, and will source your `~/.bash_profile`.